# basic file upload in rails with form helper

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get my head around the basic file upload with the form helper in Rails using the [edge rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) (I'm using rails 4.0.0.rc1 and ruby 1.9.3p362) before I get into Paperclip or CarrierWave.

I put the method for the upload right in with my #create in the Controller, my plan was to create the new record with an :image column that stored the filename of my upload.

My #create has this:

```
File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
  file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
```

When I follow the Rails Guide exactly the file upload happens, I can see the file in my `public/uploads`, but I get an encoding  error in the browser:
`Encoding::UndefinedConversionError`
`"\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`

The \x89 is the dot on the suffix of the filename? ie: .png

I found a StackOverflow post that said to add the 'b' to the File.open, that fixes the Encoding error, but I get a different error. This [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942930/how-to-write-an-image-to-filesystem-in-rails-3-1-1) covers my error, but I believe I'm following the solution and still have the error.

```
File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
```

I get the following TypeError, but no Encoding error. On the other hand, the file uploads.

```
TypeError: can't cast ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to string:
```

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong? It'd be nice to see this work before I move to Paperclip or CW

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that I was using the column `:image` for the upload, but during the uploading the `:image` is not a `:string`, it's an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object (right?). In the database the `:image` column field type is a `:string`. So what I want to store in `:image` is the `uploaded_io.original_filename`.

My first solution to make it work was not use ':image' as the `f.file_field` in the form_for. I'm calling it `:filename` instead, then grab the `uploaded_io.original_filename` from that object and store it in `:image`, then do my save.

This is ugly, but it works.

```
uploaded_io = params[:piture][:filename]
File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
@picture.image = uploaded_io.original_filename
```

I'm still a little hazy on the file.write(upload_io.read) vs File.open(...)

Comment: I haven't checked out carrierwave yet, sorry.

Comment: I ended up using paperclip which was much more rails 4 friendly